# Function-local inner functions

Tags: vimscript, functions

These exist with lambdas

```
function A()

  let B = { -> 'thing' }

endfunction

// B does no exist
```

But the lambda returns a value and not a sequence of commands.

(I know I could put execute("..") in the lambda but this is an ugly hack.)

```
function A()

  function B()
    echo "I'm going to leak"
  endfunction

endfunction

// B exists everywhere now
```

Now we can `call B()` from outside `A`, so it's not local to the function.

So, is it possible to have a function-local inner functions?

(I want to pass closure callbacks without redefining a script-local function every time.)

Comment: I wonder if dictionary functions would work? Alternate parameterize the body as a function and return a lambda invoking the function.

Comment: I was thinking lambdas are not evaluated until called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to prevent creation of a global function is to use "dictionary entry funcref syntax."  Note that this is distinct, but also useful paired with, functions which are marked `dict`.

```
function A()
  let l:container = {}

  function container.myfunc()
    echo "I'm going to leak"
  endfunction

  call l:container.myfunc()
  return l:container.myfunc
endfunction
```

Internally, vim is creating a "numbered" function stored in a funcref type variable.  This is very similar to how a lambda is implemented.  Although you can return the funcref value and safely call it outside, once all references are gone, it is cleaned up.

You can also use the `closure` keyword to allow use of outside variables, like is the default for a lambda.  Use care, because it is rather easy to create circular references in this way, and vim will not clean up resources if references exist.

```
function A()
  let l:value = 10
  let l:container = {}

  function container.myfunc() closure
    echo "Variable" l:value
  endfunction

  call l:container.myfunc()
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's a little ugly but it's exactly what I want.

Comment: Regarding another comment, the above function can work as a closure too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course.

```
function! Outer() abort
    let l:time = strftime("%c")

    function! s:inner(param) abort closure
        echom "Inner closure was created at" l:time
        echom "Param is" a:param
    endfunction

    return funcref("s:inner")
endfunction

let g:Inner = Outer()
call g:Inner(42)
```

Comment: Nice! I always forget about `closure` clause.

Comment: `s:inner` can be called outside `Outer`. So it's not local to the function. I'll make my post clearer.

Comment: @mmm111mmm In VimScript any function can be called if you know its name.

Comment: @Matt See the accepted answer. Mass has an interesting solution

Comment: @mmm111mmm It's not a closure.

Comment: Just add `closure` and it is